# How to return stuff from the dictionary and multiply them all?

Tags: python, list

So I'm trying to multiply every single number that is assigned to each variable in dictionary `output` and I created a function `totalcalories(inputlst)` to find it.

So what I'm trying to do is to define a function `totalcalories(inputlst)` that will return the total number of calories consumed based on every meal you eat.

The calories will be stored in a dictionary like this...

```
inputlst =  {"Cabbage":"4,2,0", "Carrot":"9,1,5", "Fatty Pork":"431,1,5"}
```

where the first number will be multiplied by 5, the second will be multiplied by 5 and the third one will be multiplied by 9.

so for instance if `Cabbage` is called, (its numbers are (4,2,0)), the output should return ((4 * 5)+(2 * 5)+(0 * 9)), which is 30.

I tried to do it like this, which clearly doesn't work...

```
def totalcalories(inputlist):
    output = {inputlist}
    g= []
    for x in output:
        g.append(x)
    return g
print(totalcalories(["Cabbage"]))
```

I'm really new to this, so please try to use dictionaries and simple beginner programming tricks to help me out, Thank you:)

Comment: I am confused: how does *the output should return ((45)+(25)+(0*9)), which is 30.* work?

Comment: That was a typo sorry.. I used (*) , which wasintended to be a multiply sign, but it somehow got changed.. I fixed it

Comment: @nikeros its (4 times 5) + (2 times 5) + ( 0 times 9), which is 20 + 10 + 0 = 30

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
sum([x*y for x, y in zip(map(int, inputlst["Cabbage"].split(",")),[5,5,9])])
```

Essentially, after having parsed the list of inputs into ints, you get their respective multipliers *side-by-side* and using a list comprehension you multiply them.

The function would be:

```
def calc(name):
    return sum([x*y for x, y in zip(map(int, inputlst[name].split(",")),[5,5,9])])
```

Comment: One liners like you suggest are really hard to read/follow. I would suggest splitting it out in steps so the OP also knows what each step does. Since he clearly states "simple beginner programming tricks".

Comment: @ThePjot point taken, You know, it is a fine balance: you don't want your code to be too verbose, but at the same time it should be self explanatory. In this specific case, I think this is a simple *one liner*, with only a few operations in place for a simple task. You should have seen what I used to write in Perl :-D. As far as learning is concerned: when I find an interesting solution on this site, I do disect it myself, and this is the way you really learn - otherwise it is like a book....

Answer (score 0):

Your code attempt currently does none of the things you want it to do, so it may be best to start from scratch.

Firstly, you will want a function that will take an inputted food (as a string), and your dictionary `inputlst`, so we can begin with the below:

```
def totalcalories(food, inputlst):
    #calculate calories
```

Firstly, you're going to need to be able to acess the values associated with your food key in your dictionary. You can do this as below:

```
inputlst['Cabbage']
```

Which returns:

```
'4,2,0'
```

Your dictionary values are all strings of numbers, which makes things more complicated. It will be easier to use those numbers if you could have them as lists e.g. [4, 2, 0], but we can change the string to a list and remove ',' like below:

```
values = list(inputlst[food])
values = [x for x in values if x != ',']
```

So now you have a list of the values ready to be used, so now its a case of multiplying each value by the values you specified above (5, 5 and 9). It might be useful to add these as variables into your function if they are likely to change, but for now I'm going to write it as below:

```
output = (values[0] * 5) + (values[1] * 5) + (values[2] * 9)
```

Then you will need to add `return output` to the end of your function. Hopefully that's enough information for you to be able to put together your function now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have control over your input list or not. But if you do, try converting it to a list of integers instead of a comma separated string. Why? It requires a extra step to convert it to integers for the multiply action.

So turn it into this:

```
inputlst =  {"Cabbage":[4, 2, 0], "Carrot":[9, 1, 5], "Fatty Pork":[431, 1, 5]}
```

If you're unable to to this directly, you can easily convert your input into this, using [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
inputlst =  {"Cabbage":"4,2,0", "Carrot":"9,1,5", "Fatty Pork":"431,1,5"}
# Loop over all key and value in your dict.
for key, value in inputlst.items():
    # Split string into the separate numbers.
    new_value = value.split(',')
    # Convert them into integers using ma[.
    # map returns a map object, convert it into a list.
    inputlst[key] = list(map(int, new_value))

print(inputlst) # {'Cabbage': [4, 2, 0], 'Carrot': [9, 1, 5], 'Fatty Pork': [431, 1, 5]}
```

Then in your code, you don't need to do any conversion of the data. Making it easier for yourself and keeps it simple (KISS approach):

```
# Define a constant with our multipliers.
MULTIPLIERS = [5, 5, 9]


def totalcalories(list_of_integers):
    total = 0
    # Loop over the integers and keep track of the index of the loop.
    for i, integer_value in enumerate(list_of_integers):
        # Fetch the multiplier we want for this index.
        multiplier = MULTIPLIERS[i]
        # Apply multiply and add it to the total.
        total += (integer_value * multiplier)
    return total
```

Which we can then easily call in a for loop:

```
>>> for key, value in inputlst.items():
>>>     print(key, totalcalories(value))
Cabbage 30
Carrot 95
Fatty Pork 2205
```

Or of course just with the value you want:

```
>>> totalcalories(inputlst['Cabbage'])
30
```